# Adding entry to ArrayList() by using a non-default constructor

Tags: c#, winforms, constructor, arraylist

I am trying to save data to ArrayList() by using following code in WinForm application. The problem is when I do this my output in bookList.txtBookList.Text is `Lab_8.Book` and I can't figure out why. Hope for some tips.

**BookEntry.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;

namespace Lab_8
{
    public partial class BookEntry : Form
    {
        private ArrayList books = new ArrayList();
        private BookList bookList = new BookList();

        public BookEntry()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            books.Add(new Book(txtTitle.Text, txtFirstName.Text, 
                txtLastName.Text, txtPublisher.Text, 
                float.Parse(txtPrice.Text)));
        }

        private void btnShowBooks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (object list in books)
            {
                bookList.txtBookList.Text += list.ToString() + "\n";
            }

            bookList.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

**Book.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Lab_8
{
    class Book : Publication
    {
        private string authorFirstName, authorLastName;

        public Book()
        { }

        public Book(string title, string firstName, string lastName, string publisherName, float price)
        : base(title, publisherName, price)
        {
            this.authorFirstName = firstName;
            this.authorLastName = lastName;
        } 

        public string getAuthorName()
        {
            return authorFirstName + " " + authorLastName;
        }

        public string AuthorFirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return authorFirstName;
            }
            set
            {
                authorFirstName = value;
            }
        }
        public string AuthorLastName
        {
            get
            {
                return authorLastName;
            }
            set
            {
                authorLastName = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Regards. HelpNeeder

Comment: I'd expect the text to be "Lab_8.Book". What are you expecting instead that you think this is wrong?

Comment: Well, as one of helpers pointed out, I should have call the Book object itself instead of object. This caused to display only the object's name as a result. I like learning on my mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the `Book` doesn't override `ToString`, which means this loop:

```
foreach (object list in books)
{
  bookList.txtBookList.Text += list.ToString() + "\n";
}
```

Will just print out the name of the class (with the namespace), or `Lab_8.Book`.

In order to correct this, you could [override `ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in `Book`:

```
class Book : Publication
{
   // .. Your code...

   public override string ToString()
   {
       return this.Title + " by " + this.AuthorFirstName + " " + this.AuthorLastName;
   }
```

That being said, I would highly recommend converting the `ArrayList` to use `List<Book>` instead.  This will allow you to refer to the books as a book directly, ie:

```
foreach (Book book in books)
{
  bookList.txtBookList.Text += book.AuthorFirstName + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

The only change required for this would be to change:

```
private ArrayList books = new ArrayList();
```

To:

```
private List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
```

And then also change the list as above...

Comment: The class diagram I am using doesn't specify anything about overwriting default ToString() method. What should I do to avoid this problem?

Comment: @HelpNeeder: I edited my answer to show you how you'd include that, if you want...

Comment: Absolutely wonderful! You saved me some googling on how to make a newline in textbox. The problem was with the Book object as I see. I wasn't sure if I could even do that.

Comment: Granted, this is quite obsolete, but it should be noted that if you have an ArrayList that is known to contain only books, you may safely write `foreach (Book book in arrayListOfBooks)` ... the compiler adds the run-time type checks.

Comment: @phoog: Yes, you can do that in a `foreach` - but not elsewhere (ie: just accessing the elements)

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your ArrayList to a List.

Then you will have a strongly typed `List` of `Book`'s as well as all the benefits of the `IEnumerable` interface.  This will make your code much more easier to read.

Because you have

```
foreach (object book in books)
```

This will take the default implementation of `ToString()` because the `book` is `System.Object`.  Calling `System.Object.ToString()` will return the name of the class.  In this case, `Lab_8.Book`.

Comment: This isn't quite right.  The reason the default implementation of ToString is called is because Book doesn't override ToString.  Consider `foreach (Book book in books)`: the compiler will add a cast from `object` to `Book`, but the result won't change, despite the fact that the static type of the variable has changed.  Conversely, if the Book class overrides ToString, that implementation will be called, whether the static type of the variable is object or Book.

Comment: To be clear: it isn't "quite right" to say "This will take the default implementation of ToString() because the book is System.Object."